# How do you create a Spring MVC that just prints some text to the screen after finishing a task?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to create a simple handler that performs a single task and then prints the word "Done" to the screen.

Do I need to create a View template or is there an easy way to print text to the screen without writing a template?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/simple_handler", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void simpleHandler(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model){
 this.carryOutSomeTask();
 // Print "Done" on the screen
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody

You just have to use

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/simple_handler", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
 public void simpleHandler(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model){
     this.carryOutSomeTask();
     return "Done";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/simple_handler", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void simpleHandler(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model){
  model.addAttribute("msg","Hello World");
}
```

In JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
    <p>This is my message: ${msg}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/simple_handler", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String simpleHandler(){
    this.carryOutSomeTask();
    return "Done";
}
```

I have used this with a lot of Ajax related projects, to return a button text for example:

```
@RequestMapping("/startMonitor")
public @ResponseBody String startMonitor() {

   printService.getMonitor().start();
   return MONITOR_STARTED;
}
```